# Calc related question. Pls help and would u kindly show me step by step how to solve it?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Use polar coordinates to set up and evaluate the double integral
$$f(x, y) = x+y $$ 
$$ R: x^2+y^2 \leq 25$$ 
 with $ x \geq  0 , y \geq 0 $

I know this is a circle and all. But the area they are talking about is $1/4$ of a circle. Is it a different formula from a half of a circle? I'm confused about what to do. I really need all the help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually  a quarter circle not a half circle because both your x and y are positive so you are in the first quadrant.

The integral is  $$\int _0^{\pi /2} \int _0^5 (r\cos (\theta)+    r\sin (\theta))   rdr d(\theta)$$

Comment: I got my answer to be 250/3. I thought I would need to use a different formula for a second. But it was the same one. Thank you so much for the help! >W<)/

Comment: Thank for your attention and understanding. I am glad that it worked for you.